# Getting selective fields in response when making a rest call using Springboot and feign client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, feign

I am trying to make a rest call using Spring boot, specifically using FeignClient. The entity I receive is very big. Thus, I am wondering is there a way I can limit the fields that I want to receive so that I don't consume much network resources? My limitation is that I cannot make any changes in the service I am requesting from. I can only make changes at my side.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you had control over the API code, then you could possibly use GraphQL (https://dzone.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-graphql-with-spring-boot ) , so that the API returns only the fields that you need.But you cannot alter the entity you are receiving from the API in the client(unless the rest api supports some kind of filters or parameters that will return a specific body).

If you do not need the entire response body, you may not need to create a java model to map the entity instead you can take the response as a String and then use JSONOBject to extract only the fields needed by you,but then again that would not reduce the original payload.

Comment: I agree to what you are saying, as that was my initial thought, but then I started to think maybe there is a way to reduce network traffic accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Jackson for json then jackson have annotation @JsonIgnore you can use

Comment: My implementation is on the client-side, therefore I do not have access to the source API code and hence cannot use the @JsonIgnore annotation.